# SOQL: Count of Contacts associated with Accounts that have Opportunities

Tags: soql, semi-join

I need a count of Contacts that are associated with Accounts that have ever had an Opportunity.
Here's the query as I think it should be

```
SELECT count() FROM Contact WHERE AccountID in 
    (SELECT id FROM Account WHERE AccountID in
          (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity)
    )
```

I get a malformed query error: Nesting of semi join sub-selects is not supported

My googling tells me I need to break this up into two queries, but I need to do this in Workbench for "reasons". Am I out of luck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a straightforward solution:

```
SELECT COUNT() FROM Contact 
   WHERE AccountId IN (SELECT AccountID FROM Opportunity)
```

Find all Contacts whose `AccountId` exists in any `Opportunity`. This presumes your Opportunities all have `AccountId` populated. It is technically not a required field per the [Object Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm?search_text=opportunity)

So, to be more precise:

```
SELECT COUNT() FROM Contact 
   WHERE AccountId IN (SELECT AccountID FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId != NULL)
```

Comment: Shocking no one I was overcomplicating things!!! Thank you!!!